# What pattern name is this?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

About the pattern sampled below, do anyone knows it's name or creator? It seem a variation of Builder proposed by GoF.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java)

I think it achieve the main goal of the GoF pattern with much less code. I saw in some framework and started using it a lot, but can't find it's proporser.
Thanks for the help.

```java
 public class User {

        private String name;

        public User name(String name) {
            setName(name);
            return this;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's just a class with a constructor, and a getter and setter method.  Not sure what you were expecting; not everything has (or even should have) its own name.

Comment: Yes the pattern is called "Confused User" pattern

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, it's just a method returning this. This is used in order to initialize an object with a fluent API instead of having to repeat the variable name: instead of `user.setFirstName("JB"); user.setLastName("Nizet");`, you can use `user.firstName("JB").lastName("Nizet");`.

Comment: Ah, well that would be a "Fluent Interface," then.

Comment: This is often called a fluent interface: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java

Comment: And now we've said it *three times.*  Forsuth, tally ho.

Comment: We used to just call it "method chaining" before everything became "fluent".

Comment: I prefer the method chaining name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for this, to avoid an error for having the same name for member and method:

```
public class User {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public User setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

User user = (new User()).setName('Me').setPhone('1234');
```

It seems the name of the pattern is 'fluent interface', while 'method chaining' is called its implementation of chaining methods. Practically, they describe the same thing but 'fluent interface' was the name generally accepted for the pattern.

You can chain more methods(not only for setting properties) including different objects:

```
user.addBall(ball)
    .inflateAllBalls()
    .getFirstBall() // returns a ball
    .roll() // roll is a method in the Ball class
    .setColor("red");
```

The cons of overusing method chaining:

- you can not check the objects to avoid null pointer exceptions(this is the biggest drawback IMO)
- the methods will return 'this' object, which is counterintuitive(see setName in my example)
- when returning other objects, like the ball object the readability of the code is decreased
- when calling methods in the same row. it becomes a bit more difficult to debug because you put the breakpoint at the row where there could be 10 methods chained.

Comment: I usually prefer `withX()` over `setX()` for these

Comment: If you chain with Optional, and use it correctly, you can avoid NPE, too

Comment: but in that case, we would have a lot of boilerplate code(while method chaining has the advantage to make the code more readable and a better fit for intelisense)

Comment: @cricket_007 that's just to help with the code completion. When you type 'w' you'll see a long list, but when you type 'n' you'll see just a few. There are goods and bads there, you can balance them.

Comment: @lauksas I don't do it for the auto complete. I think to myself, I'm creating an object "with" that field-value. It's taught everywhere I've seen that setter methods are almost always returning void, so just having a different convention make it stand out better

Comment: I got what you mean @cricket_007, that's valuable, yes. But I do like to follow unclebob martin tips as well on clean code to speed up development. I think most cases both would fit as long as you use it all across you code.

Comment: @lauksas If you literally want clean code along with this pattern in Java, look at using Lombok. Otherwise, Scala and Kotlin offer data classes that remove the needs for explicitly defining getters and setters

Comment: This seems  a nice tip @cricket_007, thank you. This java framework seems to be useful! In fact this could become a JSR.

In the other hand, naming things with different beginnings is a way of life. Try it out, this uncle bob martin tip saved me a lot of typing and clicks :)